# What is this bracelet on Zelenskyy's wrist?

Tags: ukraine, volodymyr-zelenskyy

When reading some article recently, I noticed that Zelenskyy is wearing a thin black bracelet around his left wrist:

[image: Zelenskyy with a bracelet]

Looking at other pictures of him, past and present, I didn't notice that bracelet, or any other accessory.

Is there any meaning to this item? Political, or other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Might be some version of a [Symbol of Perseverance](https://www.president.gov.ua/en/news/simvol-nezlamnosti-platforma-united24-prezentuvala-brasleti-78317) in which case it would be political.

Fundraising platform [United24](https://u24.gov.ua/), initiated by President Volodymyr Zelenskyy, launched the project "Azovstal. A Symbol of Perseverance" to raise funds to support Ukraine during the war. The first part of the initiative is the charitable release of bracelets made from the last pre-war batch of metal from the Azovstal plant. It would be not be strange for Volodymyr Zelenskyy to wear the bracelet with the goal of promoting the United24.

The bracelet in the source looks slightly different from the one pictured in your photo but it may be several versions of them.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that is it.